Traveling to Montenegro with Single-Entry Schengen Visa
I am planning to travel to Italy, Croatia, and Montenegro with my Schengen Visa. Do I have to apply for a multiple-entry schengen visa if I'm planning to go back to my country (Indonesia) straight from Montenegro? Since there will be no re-entering back to Schengen area, I thought a single-entry visa might suffice. However, I'm reading that to enter Montenegro with a Schengen visa, it should be a multiple-entry visa. Can anyone clarify?

Is there a direct flight between Montenegro and Indonesia? Else requirements for transit may change things (or help).

To enter Montenegro visa free, Indonesian citizens need a valid Schengen visa. A single entry visa would cease to be valid upon leaving Croatia. So you need a multiple entry visa for the entire duration of your trip, or you could change the order of your itinerary and go to Montenegro before going to a Schengen country.
Source: Visit Montenegro

Or you could get a separate visa from Montenegro.
